# How to disable highlighting of scope when opening curly braces?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since Feb update I noticed that when opening a curly brace, I get the scope highlighted, not when browsing the code, only when opening a curly brace.

[image: highlight curly braces' scope]

How do I turn off this?

Comment: I don't see this (at least in a javascript file).  Could it be some extension doing it?  You could disable them all and see if you still get the highlighted scope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Indeed, I don't have this at home, I'll investigate in the office tomorrow :)